# TextFile to Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have different input text files i need to parse them to dictionary . 
The first line contains an integer, N, denoting the number of entries in the phone book. 
Each of the N subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of 22 space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's namename, and the second value is an 88-digit phone numberphone number.

After the N lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a namename to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

Note: Names consist of lowercase English letters and are first names only.
Here are some sample inputs files .

**Sample 1:**
3 // total three entries

john

34087423764 //8 digit phone number

abc

34087423123 //8 digit phone number

dce

24589756

dce

abc

three

**Sample 2:**

100000

mued 40502760

reiw 53841370

gkry 12304153

clrb 52664724

rbrq

xxxx

nlvk

qfrw

negg

Now i wrote a program to handle it but i dont know how to handle sample 2 and how to identify the queries any ideas how to handle first line then other samples

```
Dictionary<String, long> phoneNumber = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        int counter = 0;

        int N = 0;
        //Reading Input Sample Text File 
        String filePath = @"c:\TextFiles\textInput.txt";
        String QueryFilePath= @"c:\TextFiles\Queries.txt";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            StreamReader sreamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string line = string.Empty;
            long key = 0;
            string value = string.Empty;
            while ((line = sreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //value = Regex.Match(line, "\\d+").Value;

                key = Convert.ToInt64(Regex.Match(line, "\\d+").Value);
                value = (Regex.Match(line, "\\D+").Value).TrimStart(',');
               phoneNumber.Add(Convert.ToString(value), Convert.ToInt64(key));
            }
            sreamReader.Close();
            if (File.Exists(QueryFilePath))
            {
                StreamReader queryFileStreatReader = new StreamReader(QueryFilePath);
                string lines = string.Empty;
                string values = string.Empty;
                while ((lines = queryFileStreatReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    values = (Regex.Match(lines, "\\D+").Value).TrimStart(',');
                    if (phoneNumber.ContainsKey(values) == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", values, phoneNumber[values]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not found");
                    }
                }
                queryFileStreatReader.Close();

            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Just use String Split method to separate around spaces :  string array[] = input.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

Comment: Could you, please, format out the samples (esp. line breaks)?

Comment: formated text can you see them now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem infect it was not well described in problem statement created a lot of confusion .

```
class Solution {
public static Dictionary<String, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
static void Main(String[] args) {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution */
        //string searchText = "sam";
        Int32 N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string readData = "";
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        {
            readData = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readData.Trim().Contains(" "))
                if (!phoneBook.ContainsKey(readData.Trim().Split(' ')[0]))
                    phoneBook.Add(readData.Trim().Split(' ')[0], readData.Trim().Split(' ')[1]);
        }

        while ((readData = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            SearchPhoneNumbers(readData.Trim());

    }
    public static void SearchPhoneNumbers(string searchQuery)
    {
        if (phoneBook.ContainsKey(searchQuery))
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", searchQuery, phoneBook[searchQuery]);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    }
}
```